# R geom_point and ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I want to plot a ggmap in R, for example, of Australia and have a layer of data points with markers corresponding to the size specified by the following data:

```
sitename   lat    lon    sitenum
Sydney     -34    151    1
Melbourne  -37    144    4
Adelaide   -34    138    7
```

Here's my code, but it's not working...

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(location = 'Australia', zoom = 4)
mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = sitenum), alpha = .5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the points as the data argument to `geom_points`. If they are in the `data.frame` `pp`, then the following will owrk

```
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = pp, aes(x =lon, y= lat,size = sitenum), alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to follow up, how do I pass the points as the data argument? Sorry, I'm brand new to R! Thanks again!

Comment: see the `data = pp` in `geom_point`. That is telling `geom_point` to use the data.frame `pp` to source the mapped variables.