# Error while producing choropleth map with maptoools

Tags: r, gis, r-maptools

Hello, I am new to GIS with R and have been trying to create a choropleth map. I successfully created a choropleth map with ggplot2 and the fortify function, but it is not that easy to add more layers on the top of a map with ggplot2. Instead I am using maptools to plot a choropleth map and later add more layers as needed for my analysis.

The choropleth map I am trying to plot is the level of unemployment for Allegheny county by census tract. the files are available here:

shapefile https://www.dropbox.com/s/uci5g2ekeq9niww/census%20tract%20allegheyny%202010.shp

csv file https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nq8nnxftot8iya/allegheyny%20socioeconomic%20info.csv

And here is my code

```
library(rgdal)
library(RArcInfo)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(classInt)
```

we load the csv file, clean it and create a subset with Id2 and unemployment

```
data<- read.csv('allegheyny socioeconomic info.csv',dec='.',
                header=T)
data$Id2<-as.numeric(as.character(data$Id2))
data$Percent.Unemployed<-as.numeric(as.character(data$Percent.Unemployed))
names(data)[names(data)=="Percent.Unemployed"]<-'unemployed'
data1<-subset(data, select= c('Id2', 'unemployed'))
```

load shapefile of Allegheny County census tracts for 2010

```
tracts<-readShapePoly("census tract allegheyny 2010.shp")
names(tracts)[names(tracts)=="GEOID10"]<-'Id2'
```

#### merge the data by Id2

```
tr1<-merge(data1,tracts)                     
sort(tr1$Id2)
colours<-brewer.pal(5, 'Greens')
breaks<- classIntervals(tr1$unemployed, n=5, style='sd')
plot(tr1, col=colours[findInterval(tr1$unemployed, breaks, all.inside=T), axes=F])
```

And this is the message I get:

```
Error in x[-1L] >= x[-n] : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

Comment: Type: `traceback()` ... report the results.

Comment: After doing a couple of steps and then looking at data1 with str() I need to ask: Why would you want a variable named 'Id2' to be class 'numeric'? I would have thought it should be character. (I also get an error opening that shape file.)

Comment: Regarding the Id2, even though it is an id variable it is numeric and sometimes there are issues when merging with csv files. Also I uploaded all of the other files to properly read the shape file. This is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gycwkruqx4msmlf/GIS.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(tracts,col=colours[findInterval(tr1$unemployed, breaks$brks, all.inside=T)])
```

Produces this:

[image]

To answer your question specifically:

The reason for the error is that `findInteerval(...)` takes as its second argument a vector of numeric. But

```
 breaks<- classIntervals(tr1$unemployed, n=5, style='sd')
```

produces a list with two elements: 'var' and 'brks'. You need to use `breaks$brks` in `findInterval(...)`.

Your statement

```
plot(tr1, col=colours[findInterval(tr1$unemployed, breaks, all.inside=T), axes=F])
```

attempts to plot `tr1`, which is not a map, it's a data frame with 402 rows. You need to `plot(tracts,...)`

Finally, why do you believe it is difficult to add layers in ggplot??

Comment: @jhoward: Have you ever looked at the documentation present in `?layers`? Report back if you think someone would get value out of that page.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it works perfectly. The only reason why ggplot2 seems confusing, to me a newbie, is the fact that I do not really understand how to add more layers without messing up the code, while with plot you just enable the option add=T.

Comment: I will take a look at the documentation present in ?layers.

Comment: It's actually in ?layer that I am complaining about, there being no page at either ?layers or at ?ggplot2::+ or ?ggplot2::+ .... oh heck, I give up; I cannot get SO Markdown to display the plus sign surrounded by single backticks. Contrast that with what you see in the lattice/trellis documentation for the "+" method: ?latticeExtra::`+.trellis` . (You do need the backticks surrounding the expression after the "::".)

Comment: @DWin: Are you referring to `?layer` in the `latticeExtra` package? I'm not really familiar with `lattice` - I try to do everything using `ggplot` if at all possible.

Comment: @jesusleal: The answer to [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20482822/) includes a map of the world with a separate layer identifying intensity and depth of earthquakes. The `ggplot` code is actually fairly simple.